# Error when Installing eris Blockchain

Tags: eris-industries

```
eloiim:~ iivri.andre$ brew install eris docker-machine virtualbox
Updating Homebrew...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/core).
==> Updated Formulae
megatools

Error: No available formula with the name "virtualbox" 
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
These formulae were found in taps:
Caskroom/cask/virtualbox-extension-pack
Caskroom/cask/virtualbox
Caskroom/versions/virtualbox-beta
Caskroom/versions/virtualbox-extension-pack-beta
To install one of them, run (for example):
brew install Caskroom/cask/virtualbox-extension-pack
```

THIS is the error I am getting when trying to install eris. How do I fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

The error is self explanatory if you read,

```
## These formulae were found in taps:
Caskroom/cask/virtualbox-extension-pack
Caskroom/cask/virtualbox
Caskroom/versions/virtualbox-beta
Caskroom/versions/virtualbox-extension-pack-beta
```

To install one of them, run (for example):

```
brew install Caskroom/cask/virtualbox-extension-pack
```

Comment: Thank You for the response I should have made it clear that I wanted help to decide which one should be installed. :)